# Best way to set transient attribute on entity instance after Metadata.create

Tags: cuba-platform

I'm currently setting the **result of a jpql query** on a **transient attribut**e of several instances of entities attached with composition using **BeforeDetachEntityListener**.
Since I'm also using Metadata.create to create them, **I would like to be able to do the same operation after creating them**. What's the best way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set values at object creation time with `@PostConstruct`

```
public class MyEntity extends StandardEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    protected User creator;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
       setCreator(AppBeans.get(UserSessionSource.class).getUserSession().getUser());
    }
}
```

More information about how to initialize data in entities can be found in the docs at [5.8.3.1  Entity Fields Initialization](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.3/init_values_in_class.html) and [5.8.3 Assigning Initial Values](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.3/init_values.html)